# PHP syntax error, unexpected '[' happens on host server, not local server... Weird?

Tags: php

I'm having a strange error which I haven't been successfully able to google a result for or find an explanation i can understand on stackOverflow. My code works fine on my local server, performing as I expect, but when I upload it, it returns the following error '*syntax error, unexpected '['in /home/maxster/max-o-matic.com/_inc/functions.php on line 59*'.

Below is line #59:

```
$aaPlaceholderIndex = array_keys($aaPlaceholder)[$row*4+$image]; //if associative array
```

Here is the whole function:

```
function PrintFolio($aaPlaceholder)

{
//print out X number rows, four items at time

$itemsCount = sizeof($aaPlaceholder);//get size of array
$height = (int)ceil(sizeof($aaPlaceholder)/4);//get size of array divided by 4

//loop through array of X items, for each group of 4 print as a row
for($row = 0; $row < $height; $row++) //looping through the rows

    {
        echo '<div class="row flush">'; //open div
        for($image = 0; $image < 4; $image++)    //each row is composed of 4 images
        {
             //$aaPlaceholderIndex = $row*4+$image; //if indexed array
             $aaPlaceholderIndex = array_keys($aaPlaceholder)[$row*4+$image]; //if associative array
             if( $aaPlaceholderIndex <= $itemsCount ) {
                 printf(TEMPLATE_PORTFOLIO, $aaPlaceholderIndex, $aaPlaceholder[$aaPlaceholderIndex]);
                 //$template = '<div class="3u"><a href="_img/fulls/%1$s" class="image full"><img src="_img/thumbs/%1$s" alt="" title="%2$s" /></a></div>';
            }
        }

        echo '</div>'; //end div group of 4
    }//end loop
}//end function
```

I'm scratching my head on this one a lot as it seems like the function is fine, it's format seems proper to me and everything is in a logical place with a good flow. I'm sure it could be better, but for me this is really good given my skill level - i'm a newb. Any thoughts on what be causing the issue with the Square brace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Array Dereferencing was not introduced until PHP 5.4. Your production version is not running PHP 5.4 but your local environment is. So:

```
$aaPlaceholderIndex = array_keys($aaPlaceholder)[$row*4+$image]; //if associative array
```

becomes:

```
$tempArray = array_keys($aaPlaceholder); //if associative array
$aaPlaceholderIndex = $tempArray[$row*4+$image]
```

Comment: So it's that my host environment is running an earlier version of php. WOW, the things you learn by asking. Thank you I will explore this and look into upgrading my server. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Quick note following on from John Conde's answer in case it's useful for anyone else - I had the same issue which was fixed by upgrading PHP, which I did by adding the following to .htaccess

```
AddType x-httpd-php55 .php
```

I don't know if this will work on all servers, but it was a quick and easy fix for me :)